# Finding length of each line segment passing through centroid , and how to constrict the line till outer contour

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSZyX.png)

[Processed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFDia.png)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


img = cv2.imread('Image(i).png', 0)
ret, img =cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img_bw = img<=120
img_bw =img_bw.astype('uint8') 
#Fit the ellipses
contours0, hierarchy = cv2.findContours( img.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
outer_ellipse = [cv2.approxPolyDP(contours0[0], 0.1, True)]
inner_ellipse = [cv2.approxPolyDP(contours0[0], 0.1, True)]
ref = np.zeros_like(img_bw)
out=img.copy()
h, w = img.shape[:2]
vis = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours( vis, outer_ellipse, -1, (255,0,0), 1)
cv2.drawContours( vis, inner_ellipse, -1, (0,0,255), 1)

##Extract contour of ellipses
cnt_outer = np.vstack(outer_ellipse).squeeze()
cnt_inner = np.vstack(inner_ellipse).squeeze()

#Determine centroid
M = cv2.moments(cnt_inner)
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
print (cx, cy)

#Draw full segment lines 
#cv2.line(vis,(cx,0),(cx,w),(150,0,0),1)

width = img.shape[1]
height = img.shape[0]
N = 20
for i in range(N):
 tmp = np.zeros_like(img_bw)
 theta = i*(360/N)
 theta *= np.pi/180.0
 cv2.line(tmp, (cx, cy),
       (int(cx-np.cos(theta)*w),
         int(cy+np.sin(theta)*h)), (150,0,0), 1)
    
(row,col) = np.nonzero(np.logical_and(tmp, ref))
     
#cv2.line(out, (cx, cy), (col,row),(255,0,0), 1)
    
    # Show the image
    
cv2.imshow('Output', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As seen in processed image the lines passing through centroid are not constricted till outer contour and are passing trough it.

**I want the lines to be stopped at the outer contour so  as that I can measure distance from centroid to the outer contour.
First image is the input image and second image is of line segments passing through centroid.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible approach:

- draw your outer contour filled with black on a white background

You now have a black ellipse. Then, without actually drawing anything:

- use [skimage.draw.line](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.line://) to get the list of points along all your radii
- use Numpy `argmax()` to get first white pixel along radii

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import math
from skimage.draw import line
import numpy as np


# Load image as greyscale
img = cv2.imread('ellipses.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_, img = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
h, w = img.shape

#Fit the ellipses
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours( img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
outer_ellipse = [cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[0], 0.1, True)]

# Draw outer contour filled with black on white background
vis = np.zeros_like(img) + 255
cnt = cv2.drawContours(vis, outer_ellipse, -1, 0, -1)

# Centroid by existing method
cx, cy = 365, 335

maxThickness = 0
# Take 10 points along top
for x in range(0,w,int(w/10)):
    # ... and bottom
    for y in 0, h-1:
        # Get y and x of all pixels between centroid and top and bottom edge
        yy, xx = line(cy, cx, 0, x)
        firstWhiteIndex = np.argmax(vis[yy,xx])
        fx, fy = xx[firstWhiteIndex], yy[firstWhiteIndex]
        # Get length of this radial line
        length = np.sqrt((cx-fx)**2 + (cy-fy)**2)
        # Remember if longer than all others so far seen
        if length > maxThickness:
            maxThickness = length
            fxMax, fyMax = fx, fy
    
# Take 10 points down left side
for y in range(0,h,int(h/10)):
    # ... and right
    for x in 0, w-1:
        # Get y and x of all pixels between centroid and left and right edge
        yy, xx = line(cy, cx, 0, x)
        firstWhiteIndex = np.argmax(vis[yy,xx])
        fx, fy = xx[firstWhiteIndex], yy[firstWhiteIndex]
        # Get length of this radial line
        length = np.sqrt((cx-fx)**2 + (cy-fy)**2)
        # Remember if longer than all others so far seen
        if length > maxThickness:
            maxThickness = length
            fxMax, fyMax = fx, fy

print(f'Max thickness: {maxThickness}')
# Draw thickest radius in mid-grey
cv2.line(img, (cx,cy), (fxMax, fyMax), 128, 5)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', img)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach that is not the best but this is what I can think of now.

While drawing lines in the above image, modify the code and do the following:

- Before the for loop, draw a binary image of the same size containing only the outer contour circle. Save this image for later use.
- Now in the for loop, draw each line in a separate binary blank image. Thus, now you will have two images, first the image having only the outer circle, and second image will only contain the line.
- Now perform a bitwise_and operation on these 2 images.
- Now you will get a white pixel only that is the point of intersection of the line and the outer circle.
- Now find the coordinates of the white pixel in the image found and hence you will have the coordinate of point of intersection.

Obviously this is not the most efficient way but it is real time. Also, keep this in mind that the outer circle width should be atleast 2 in the image and the lines should be of width 1. You may get more than one point of intersection in some cases, take any 1 of them. The difference in them will be only of 1-2 pixels that can be neglected.